# Packages and the like for configuring new systems

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, utilities

I'm faced with the prospect of moving from a server which has been configured previously with loads and loads of the sorts of tools you forget about day-to-day as you do various tasks (I'm talking about even the basic stuff like java and gcc etc), to a completely bare box (actually several, but I only really need to configure the first then I can just image the rest).

I was wondering if anyone has a list of their own particular 'must-haves', and also whether there are any sort of 'ready made' collections of all the day-to-day useful stuff to have in a unix (ubuntu specifically) shell.

On mac for instance, I've seen people make scripts to install all their favourite homebrew apps without having to do them one by one.

Just want to speed up and simplify the job of installing all the bog-standard bits and peices - but I don't know where to look?

Answer (score 1):

This might be pointing the obvious, but you and only you can tell what is important and what is not, and create a install script depending on what you need. Scripting is not hard. If you are on a RedHat compliant system, all you need is a series of `yum install <package_Name>` commands. If you are going to use a Debian variant, the command changes to `apt-get install package_name`. You may need to manually add the repository names for few esoteric apps, but other than that, it should go smoothly.

If you want to know what was installed on your previous system, you can get that information by

```
rpm -qa    #on RedHat variants
dpkg --get-selections    #on debian variants
```

just massage the output with sed/awk/grep.

Comment: On Debian-based systems the output of `apt-mark showauto` should also be preserved, so that automatically installed packages can be re-flagged after re-installation (using `dpkg --get-selections`' output).

Comment: Yes this is the sort of thing I was getting at, but I wondered if there are any out there that people use often? Kind of like a "swiss-army-knife" installation of loads of useful things.

I can script it easy enough, but my thinking was  that there might already be widely used examples.

Not strictly limited to things that are installed by `apt-get` or `yum` as well.

In much the same way there there are threads comparing people's go-to functions etc in their `.bashrc`'s, I thought a list of people's go-to packages etc might be enlightening too.